Laravel Sanctum: user is null even a bearer token is provided
I have a login function:
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => [ 'The provided credentials are not correct' ]
        ]);
    }

    $user = $request->user();

    $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;
    
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'User login successfully.',
        'data' => [
            'token' => $token
        ]
    ]);
}

with this route:
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

When I call the route with curl
curl -X POST --header 'Accept: application/json' -d "email=my_email@example.org&password=abcd1234" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login"

I get the result of something like this:
{"success":true,"message":"User login successfully.","data":{"token":"5|mjUhxKPAsRqADS9y1vXcEANHw7l9dvYelOXV12IM4d579c2f"}}

which is expected.
Now, when I call this curl command:
curl -X POST --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 5|mjUhxKPAsRqADS9y1vXcEANHw7l9dvYelOXV12IM4d579c2f' "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user"

and I have a route like this:
Route::post('/user', function(Request $request) {
    var_dump($request->user());
    return response()->json($request->user());
});

then I get
NULL
{}

as a result, not my user stuff.
But I expect a user because I provided a bearer token. Why I am getting NULL here?

You should make sure you are using auth:sanctum middleware on your route.

var_dump(auth(“sanctum”)->user())

Solution is to use the auth:sanctum middleware, i.e.:
Route::post('/user', function(Request $request) {
    var_dump($request->user());
    return response()->json($request->user());
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');

